# Find the $\alpha$-level uniformly most powerful test (UMPT) of Poisson distribution

Tags: hypothesis-testing, self-study, poisson-distribution

Let $(X_1, X_2, X_3)$ be a sample from $Poisson(\lambda)$. Here we test $H_0: \lambda\le 1$ v.s. $H_1: \lambda>1$. Fix $\alpha=0.05$. Find the $\alpha$-level uniformly most powerful test (UMPT).

---

My work: note that the density function has monotone likelihood ratio on $T=\sum_{i=1}^3 X_i$.

By [Karlin-Rubin theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_most_powerful_test), the UMPT for test $H_0: \lambda\le 1$ v.s. $H_1: \lambda>1$ is given by
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_n)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } T>k\\
\gamma & \text{if } T=k\\
        0 & \text{if } T<k
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the rejection region is the likelihood ratio $\Lambda>k$, and $k$ and $\gamma$ are decided by
$$
\alpha=P_{\lambda_0}(T>k)+\gamma P_{\lambda_0}(T=k).
$$

Now my problem is, it seems that I can't solve the gamma. I read this theorem, and some people can't write this gamma, especially for continuous functions. Do we need to consider gamma? I mean the test function is:
\begin{equation}
\Phi(X_1,\dots,X_n)=
    \begin{cases}
        1 & \text{if } T>k\\
        0 & \text{if } T\le k
    \end{cases}
\end{equation}
where the rejection region is the likelihood ratio $\Lambda>k$, and $k$ and $\gamma$ are decided by
$$
\alpha=P_{\lambda_0}(T>k).
$$

If this one holds, we can solve $k$...

Comment: $P_{\lambda_0}(T>k)$ is not a continuous function of $k$ for a discrete distribution - it jumps at each integer - so for most $\alpha$ you cannot find a $k$ satisfying $\alpha=P_{\lambda_0}(T>k)$.  What did you get for $k$ when you tried to find the critical region in this particular case?

Answer (score 3):

An apt quote ($\rm [I]$):

> ...  First $k$ is adjusted so that $P_0(L(X) > k)$  and $P_0(L(X) \geq k)$ bracket $\alpha,$ and then a value $\gamma\in [0, 1]$ is chosen for $\varphi(X)$ when $L(X) = k $ to achieve level $\alpha.$

$T(\mathbf X)\sim \mathrm{Poi}(3).$ A quick look at $\mathtt R:$

```
> qpois(0.95, 3)
[1] 6
> ppois(6, 3)
[1] 0.9664915
> ppois(7, 3)
[1] 0.9880955
> ppois(5, 3)
[1] 0.916082
```

Now can you choose a particular $k$ from above and as per the quote, then calculate the necessary $\gamma$?

---

### Reference:

$\rm [I]$ Theoretical Statistics: Topics for a Core Course, *Robert W. Keener,* Springer Science$+$Business Media, $2010,$ p. $224.$

Comment: So the value of $\gamma$ and $K$ are not unique?

Comment: MP tests agree with each other except on a set of measure zero. Re-read the quote. You won't find multiple $k$s.

Comment: straight to the point (+1) also for the reference to one of my preferred books!